# How does the function to curry and uncurrying another function work?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming, haskell

The following is the code to curry or uncurry a function in Haskell:

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry f a b = f (a, b)

uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
uncurry f (a, b) = f a b
```

I can understand the type signature part but not the function definition. Would you please explain me how those function bodies turn a curried function into an uncurried one and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of `curry` can be easier to be seen when the type signature is written as

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)
```

that is, a function taking a single parameter of type `(a, b)` and yielding a result of type `c` is turned into a function taking two separate values of types `a` and `b` yielding the same result type `c`.

We might define curry for this signature like this:

```
curry f = g
```

where `f :: ((a, b) -> c)` and `g :: (a -> b -> c)`.

`f` is passed by the user, but how do we get `g`? We know `g` is a function taking two parameters and yielding a result type, so it must structurally look like `\x -> \y -> z`, where `x :: a`, `y :: b`, and `z :: c` (`\v -> e` is the syntax for lambda-expressions in Haskell). We now have to find a way to get the result `z` from `x` and `y` such that the types work out correctly.

As both result types `c` must be the same, the only way to get `z` is to use `f` and apply it to a value of type `(a, b)`. So we know `z = f (?, ?)` where `(?, ?)` must have type `(a, b)`. Where do we get values of these types from? Again, as the types must match exactly, the only option is to use `x` and `y` here. We get

```
curry f = g
    where g = \x -> \y -> f (x, y)
```

This would be a proper implementation for `curry`. One that is easier to read is to inline `g`:

```
curry f = \x -> \y -> f (x, y)
```

As Haskell allows us to define functions with multiple parameters, we can resolve the lambda-expression and simplify this to

```
curry f x y = f (x, y)
```

which is (beside different variable names) the same implementation as in your question.

For `uncurry` the procedure is similar (note that you had missing parentheses in the type signature for `uncurry` in your original question which lead to a different type).

From

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
```

we conclude

```
uncurry f = g
    where g = \(x, y) -> z
```

with `f :: (a -> b -> c)`, `g :: (a, b) -> c`, `x :: a`, `y :: b` and `z :: c`. Following the types, `z` can only be defined by `z = f x y`. From that we get

```
uncurry f = g
    where g = \(x, y) -> f x y
```

and after inlining `g` and removing the lambda

```
uncurry f (x, y) = f x y
```